# Accessing Homestead Globally

Tags: global, homestead

So I've installed Homestead and Laravel going through the steps in Laravel Documentation.

One problem that occured throughout the process, is that I can't set "homestead" command, to be accessible globally.

The Documentation writes, that I should just paste that line into the temrinal:

```
alias homestead='function __homestead() { (cd ~/Homestead && vagrant $*); unset -f __homestead; }; __homestead'
```

But that only makes it accessible globally untill I restart my terminal.

I've also edited my bash_profile file, adding

```
export PATH="/Users/MacbookPro/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

to the very bottom of the file, but that does not work either.

Answer (score 2):

To make your alias works every time you open terminal, you've to put your alias into [.bashrc file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540683/what-is-a-bashrc-file-and-what-does-it-do) so it been executed every time you open a new terminal tab.

Just add `youralias` to **~/.bashrc** file

or

If you're using [ohmyz.sh](http://ohmyz.sh/) add `youralias` to **~/.zshrc** file instead.